# Prove if $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f′ >g$′ on $(a,b)$, then $f>g$ on $(a, b)$. Where f, g are differentiable and $a<b$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Suppose f and g be differentiable on an open interval. Let $a, b \in$ the interval and let $a<b$. Prove if $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f′ >g$′ on $(a,b)$, then $f>g$ on $(a b)$.

Up to this point I have Rolle's theorem, Cauchy mean value theorem, and the mean value theorem. I know that since a, b are in the open interval, f and g are continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Visually/ conceptually I understand this, but am not sure how to prove it. I think the proof involves Rolle's theorem, but I can't manipulate it to work for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Use the Mean Value Theorem on $h = f - g$.

Comment: Wouldn't this just show $f(b)>g(b)$? From the MVT we know there exists a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $h'(c) = \frac{h(b)-h(a)}{b-1} = \frac{f(b)-g(b)}{b-a}$. Conceptually, I know that since $f' > g'$ and $f(b)>g(b)$ implies that $f(x)>g(x)$, but again, I'm not sure how to prove this. I thought of taking intervals $(a, a + \delta)$, $(a +\delta, a+2\delta)$... until $n\delta$ approaches b,  then applying MVT, but this doesn't seem efficient?

Comment: To the proposer: By contradiction, if $a<c<b$ and $f(c)\leq g(c)$ then there exists $d\in (a,c)$ such that $f'(d)-g'(d)=h'(d)=$ $\frac {h(c)-h(a)}{c-a}=$ $\frac {f(c)-g(c)}{c-a}\leq 0.$

Comment: Thank you to both of you! I understand this now.